DeLing with small medical dataset
I am a medical student currently working on a dataset related to medical physics fields extracted from medical physics images. My dataset has 66 rows and 22 columns. The goal is to predict the next 5 columns with the help of the first 17 columns. data are about lungs, and lungs are very different in humans, so it's likely that the dataset has many outliers, despite the small number of samples. Some columns have normal distribution and some non-normal ones. Do you have any suggestions for me on how to deal with these outliers? I asked again and did not receive an answer. (I'm very sorry, but I'm a beginner, so I'd appreciate your guidance as easy as possible)
My data is numerical in the form of a table with 66 rows and 22 columns. Since I take the time of the boxplot diagram for each column, for most of the columns, there are 6 or 5 data outside the range of IQRs, and even for some columns, these outlier data are much more. I tried to remove outlier data with different methods such as z score, isolation forest, one class svm, but there are still outlier data and they cause extreme overfit in the models
